# Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE Bricked and not charging (gray battery)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, charging

Some time ago i had problem with my Samsung S3 LTE, namely, after some time the phone started to flash screen, lose signal and finally crash. The problem lasted about 2 months but I belittled it and just got used to it.
 Unfortunately after all that time my phone could not boot after such crash.
 I went back home and tried to solve the problem as always - charge the phone, but this time the phone was not charging, it was only displaying grey battery with a thunder in it.
 I checked my battery and saw a bulge so i replaced the battery with a new one but the problem persists. 
I tried odin but had the "can't open the serial(com) port" error.
If I try to turn the phone on, it gets stuck on the Samsung logo.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of charging Samsung Galaxy S3 if it has broken micro usb charging port is to connect directly to the terminals inside the case. This will only work with a wall charger, and you'll need some electronics know-how to do it. [This video shows how.](https://youtu.be/2DckxcYoEEw)